# CSS - Object pressed to the side because of ul basic padding

Tags: html, css

My problem is that it seems that my ul get´s a margin. I can't figure out why it doesn't go all the way to the left. this also leads to my site expanding.

```css
/* Challenge list */
.container_list{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;

}
ul {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;

    
}

ul li{
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.10);
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- All challenges -->
    <h4 id="#">All challenges</h4>
    <div class="container_list">
    <ul class="challenge_list">
        <li>This is an item</li>
        <li>This is an item</li>
        <li>This is an item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `ul` by default comes with a padding of 40px. You can remove this by explicitly setting `padding:0` on the `ul` element.

```css
/* Challenge list */

.container_list {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.10);
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- All challenges -->
<h4 id="#">All challenges</h4>
<div class="container_list">
  <ul class="challenge_list">
    <li>This is an item</li>
    <li>This is an item</li>
    <li>This is an item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you already know it's because of the default browser settings.

This can be avoided by something that's called a reset css, this removes all default browser settings for all browsers. It's easily implemented by just adding

```
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

above your default styling

Have a look at a few [reset css](https://cssreset.com/)'s and just copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

For all HTML tags, there are default CSS properties applied to them. If you don't specify a CSS property for an element, a default value for the property will be taking effect. For ul element, there is a default padding-left: 40px as shown in attached image. This is the reason, your ul element not sticking left.[image]